# CSS - how do i make the video element totally 100% width and height so that when browser resize it scale auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have following code but inside the body, #container and #localVideo is not showing 100% width and height. Also when the browser is resize its not automatically getting adjusted.

Any ide?

```
<body style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">

  <div id="container" style="width:1024px; height: 768px;
       position: absolute;margin: 0px auto;">

    <video id="localVideo" oncontextmenu="return false;"  style="width:100%; height:100%;"></video>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried making the container occupy 100% of the width and height?

Comment: what `width:1024px` doing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly set your height and width to pixel values, why would it resize?

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <video id="localVideo" ...>No Video Support!</video>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
html, body, #container, #localVideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also:

- Don't use inline styles - Please, don't.
- `height: 100%` only works when the parent element has a known height (i.e. not Auto). That's why both `html` and `body` must have it too.

Comment: `height: 100%;` wont maintain aspect ratio! :)

Comment: True, but he didn't ask for aspect ratio maintain, he specifically wanted the video to be 100% width and height, and to resize with the window.

Answer (score 3):

Try out the below responsive code for youtube embed video :

HTML

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If you go on about stealing the exact code example from a blog post, why don't you give at least credit to the author? https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 2):

Use the new [CSS viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) `vw` and `vh` (viewport width / viewport height)

You don't even need to wrap it in a container.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L0jxmr0k/1/)**

```
video {
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 75vw; /* 768/1024 = .75 */
    background:pink;  /* not needed after you add the src attribute in the video element */
}
```

Browser support is also good: IE9+ ([caniuse][3])

Answer (score -1):

If I have this problem that the height or width don't work I set the height and the width with Jquery and than it works.

If you do it with javascript you can also look for a resize and than run a size function.
than you get something like this:
(this is Jquery code)

```
$(document).resize(function(){
   size();
});

function size(){
  //inhere the code to set the height and width
}
```